# Advanced Residential Turf Hydration: Potassium Polyacrylate vs Polyacrylamide

Tags: lawn

I am having a hard time finding concrete information on the pros/cons between Potassium Polyacrylate and Polyacrylamide.  Both are super long polymer chains which are hydrophilic.  Each swell up several times their original size when exposed to H2O (water).  FYI: Sodium Polyacrylate and Potassium Polyacrylate are very similar except the salt is replaced to prevent salination as the compound breaks down either naturally or through bio-mechanisms.  Potassium is a resource the grass can breakdown further over time as a natural food source.

There are discussions that the byproducts of Polyacrylamide are carcinogenic or may act as neurotoxin with prolonged exposure.  Yet I cannot find a single white paper that confirms these assumptions in human biology.

My question is of simple nature.  Which one is better for residential lawn use and why?  Apart from the health concern, I would anticipate that the polymer that swells larger and retains more water over an extended period of time (holds onto water tighter), and breaks down over a longer period of time is the ideal candidate.

To add this is for a new lawn being started off with 50/50 screened loam and certified KBG midnight seed in the Northeast (USA).  It will later be overseeded with the cultivar "After Midnight".  The polymer only needs to last long enough for the root system of the first and secondary seeding is well established.

Comment: Aside from any carcinogenic concerns the use of hydrophilic agents is questioned as the answer to "Where does it go" is into the environment.  Just because you add it to the lawn doesn't mean it will stay there.

Comment: @kevinsky exactly.  The Potassium Polyacrylate, from what I understand, gets broken down by bacteria and other bio-organisms.  One fear for hydrophilic agents is that as they break down they become dust like which can get trapped in the digestive track of small organisms.  I believe that has been debunked as a myth by a few scientists though.  What remains is the K (potassium) which is a nutrient for the grass.  I think the polyacrylamide is similar.  Both are biodegradable.  Some last longer than others.  Their byproducts are classified as non-toxic for plants and animals.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three white papers that discuss polyacrylimade hydrogels (PAMs) in a reader-friendly manner.The first two are rather old but contain basic information.

- [The Myth of Polyacrylamide Hydrogels](https://s3.wp.wsu.edu/uploads/sites/403/2015/03/hydrogels.pdf) - Original study
- [The Myth of Polyacrylamide Hydrogels Revisited](https://s3.wp.wsu.edu/uploads/sites/403/2015/03/hydrogels-2.pdf) - Additional, newer information
- [Super-absorbent water crystals](https://s3.wp.wsu.edu/uploads/sites/403/2015/03/hydrogels-3.pdf) - Most recent

In addition, here is [a list of references about hydrogels](https://puyallup.wsu.edu/lcs/reference-polyacrylamide-gels/) that could give you much more information. Most of these may be behind paywalls, however.

Note that gels are not recommended for long-term landscape use because, at the very least, they last only 2-5 years in the soil. Now, that's not a concern for your application, but there are both human and environmental risks associated with PAMs which are discussed in more detail in the referenced papers. For example, some PAMs are toxic to aquatic insects and plants, as well as to fish.

In my opinion, hydrogels of any kind are an unnecessary additive to the landscape because proper cultural procedures will always work. In the case of a new lawn, proper seeding depth, proper mix of grass varieties for the sun exposure of the site, a covering of shredded straw on the seeded area, and proper watering will ALWAYS grow a lawn.